# iOS App Store links don't open in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ios

Opening the following links in chrome on IOS displays a wall of txt.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id362872995

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id371707711

It seems to be an issue with chrome. I was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using itmss:// instead of https://

it appears that this has been fixed in the new beta version of chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242910

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if "issue" is quite the word I'd choose, given that the App Store links apparently return `Content-Type: text/html` and thus don't really indicate, at least in an RFC2616-compliant fashion, that the user agent (Chrome, in this case) should handle them differently from an ordinary webpage. There are lots of other Apple-specific HTTP headers:

```
x-apple-lok-response-date: Thu May 30 08:43:40 PDT 2013
x-apple-translated-wo-url: /WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=362872995&cc=us
x-apple-orig-url-path: /us/app/id362872995
x-apple-application-site: ST11
apple-timing-app: 122 ms
x-apple-aka-ttl: Generated Thu May 30 08:43:40 PDT 2013, Expires Thu May 30 08:44:40 PDT 2013, TTL 60s
x-apple-application-instance: 2126047
x-webobjects-loadaverage: 0
x-apple-jingle-correlation-key: JZ6JKEFVAVIEA
X-Apple-Partner: origin.0
```

Presumably at least some of them would be enough to indicate that this is an App Store link and should be opened in that app, but Chrome currently doesn't pay attention to them.

[It would appear](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20chrome%20open%20app%20store%20links) that others have seen the issue, which is unsurprising, but I haven't found anyone who has an actual solution; I don't think it's possible for one app to launch another outside of native code, which precludes any possibility of a bookmarklet or browser extension that'd solve the problem; to do that, Google would have to bake App Store support into Chrome for iOS, which seems unlikely to occur.

Comment: You think that Safari (that actually supports itunes links) uses some undocumanted API to open AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads in Chrome (with an error of a whole bunch of jargon) try selecting "Request Desktop Site" from the options menu. The page will reload and with a bit of luck you'll be redirected to AppStore (possibly via iTunes).